# Timeout acquiring a connection when streaming results using Express

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, stream, knex.js

We use the following code to stream the results of a query back to the client:

```
app.get('/events', (req, res) => {
  try {
    const stream = db('events')
      .select('*')
      .where({ id_user: 'foo' })
      .stream()

    stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res)
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
})
```

While the code seems to have an excellent memory usage profile (stable/low memory usage) it creates random DB connection acquisition timeouts:

> Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are
> you missing a .transacting(trx) call?

This happens in production at seeming random intervals. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was painful to debug:

Alright, this happens because aborted requests (i.e client closes the browser mid-request) don't release the connection back to the pool.

First, ensure you're on the latest knex; or at least [v0.21.3+ which has introduced fixes to stream/pool handling](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2324).

From the on you have a couple options:

Either use [`stream.pipeline`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streampipelinestreams-callback) instead of [`stream.pipe`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readablepipedestination-options) which handles aborted requests correctly like so:

```
const { pipeline } = require('stream')

app.get('/events', (req, res) => {
  try {
    const stream = db('events')
      .select('*')
      .where({ id_session: req.query.id_session })
      .stream()

    return pipeline(stream, JSONStream.stringify(), res, err => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(`Pipeline failed with err:`, err)
      }

      console.log(`Pipeline ended succesfully`)
    })
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
})
```

or listen to the [`close`][close] event on `req` and destroy the DB stream yourself, like so:

```
app.get('/events', (req, res) => {
  try {
    const stream = db('events')
      .select('*')
      .where({ id_session: req.query.id_session })
      .stream()

    // Not listening to this event will crash the process if
    // stream.destroy(err) is called.
    stream.on('error', () => {
      console.log('Stream was destroyed')
    })

    req.on('close', () => {
      // stream.end() does not seem to work, only destroy()
      stream.destroy('Aborted request')
    })

    stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res)
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
})
```

### Useful reading:

- [knex Wiki: Manually close streams](https://github.com/knex/knex/wiki/Manually-Closing-Streams). Careful, the `stream.end` mentioned here doesn't seem to work.
- [knex Issue: stream.end() does not return connection to pool](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2324)